# Google apps script regex match

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I get true for the below

```
function myFunction1() {
  var text = "hello world";
  var regex = /hello/;
  var result = regex.test(text);
  console.log((result));
}
```

[image]

Why am I getting `false` for this?

```
function myFunction() {
  var array = ["2023", "2022", "2020"];
  var regex = new RegExp("^20\d{2}$");

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var result = regex.test(array[i]);
    console.log(typeof(array[i]),result);
  }
}
```

The output is `false` for all the items in the array

I also tried changing the regex pattern as `20\d{2}` but still getting `false`

[image]

Should the `result` not be `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^20\d{2}$");
```

- In this case, it is `/^20d{2}$/`. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

#### To:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^20\\d{2}$");
```

- If you want to use `^20\d{2}$`, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      var result = regex.test(array[i]);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var result = /^20\d{2}$/.test(array[i]);
    ```

#### Testing:

```js
var array = ["2023", "2022", "2020"];
var regex = new RegExp("^20\\d{2}$");

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var result = regex.test(array[i]);
  console.log(typeof(array[i]),result);
}
```

or,

```js
var array = ["2023", "2022", "2020"];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var result = /^20\d{2}$/.test(array[i]);
  console.log(typeof(array[i]),result);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)